# VBA: PowerPoints presentations are opened as Read-Only

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I try to open, change and save a presentation, but it always gets opened as Read-Only:

```
If measTypesDict.Exists(MeasType) = False Then
    Dim targetPath As String
    Dim newPres As PowerPoint.presentation

    measTypesDict.Add MeasType, New Dictionary

    Set newPres = PowerPoint.Application.Presentations.Add(msoFalse)

    targetPath = rootDir & "\final\" & MeasType & ".ppt"
    newPres.SaveAs targetPath
    ' newPres.Close that is what's been missing

    targetPresentationsDict.Add MeasType, Presentations.Open(targetPath, ReadOnly:=msoFalse, WithWindow:=msoFalse)
End If
```

From the [Microsoft Documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162555):

```
The ReadOnly parameter is used to open a presentation as Read-Only. 
The following example opens a file named test.ppt as Read-Only.

   Sub OpenPresentationReadOnly()
      Presentations.Open "c:\test.ppt", msoTrue
   End Sub
```

Can anyone give me a hint why this is the case? I am the owner of the target folder and I have full control according to the folder settings.

Comment: Is the file already saved as `Read Only`?

Comment: I think I got the solution. I was adding the presentation using `Presentations.Add(msoFalse)' and then saved is as `newPres.SaveAs targetPath`. **Now** I call `newPres.Close` and reopen that presentation. Now I have write access - but I don't really like that fact that I have to reopen it ..

Comment: If you are doing a save as then why reopen it? it is already opened...

Comment: I edited the code - take a look

Comment: Try this `targetPresentationsDict.Add MeasType,newPres`

Comment: I didn't see the forrest as I was surrounded by too many trees ..

Answer (score -1):

**Can you try this:**

```
   Sub OpenPresentation()
      Presentations.Open "c:\test.ppt"
   End Sub
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This member does not exist (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162555) and I think you are refering to Excel's API here.

Comment: @StefanFalk..just use above with out any attributes